# How to realistically explain antigravitation?

Tags: science-based, gravity, megastructures

When designing something really big, which can be compared in size with at least a planet, one problem seems to be unsolvable. The problem is how to fight the gravitational force that will collapse everything that is huge enough. The idea is to come up with a way to do gravitational shielding in such a way to build structures of arbitrary size.

The structures I am talking about are something like [The City](https://blame.fandom.com/wiki/City) from [Blame!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blame%21). The main challenge, in my opinion, is to make this shielding to work with known physics. This means that unobtanium is not the way to explain it and neither is magic or unknown technology([as it is done](https://blame.fandom.com/wiki/Megastructure) in the manga).

At first sight, the main candidate to be the form of matter that has antigravitational properties is antimatter, but today it is [almost certain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-gravity#Fifth_force) that it is not the case.

From all the sources that I have read, it seems that the [theory does not entirely forbid](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.3327545?casa_token=c8xShsLHKd0AAAAA:OZII_Vy1yi5lYCQPaxGn9vR0M33J9L93mUc3SKtu9CNpyPEljRy_HjyIdrgcIOhkOV19qhVAVYig) the existence of antigravitation, but all observations suggest that antigravitation does not exist. But here the question is to come up with a realistic explanation of antigravitation which will not obviously conflict with modern physics.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111875/discussion-on-question-by-frogofjuly-how-to-realistically-explain-antigravitatio).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dark Energy**

According to science, the expansion of the universe is [accelerating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy#cite_note-paalhorvathlukacs-28). They don't know what can cause this, so for now they use dark energy to explain the unknown phenomenon. There is evidence that something is active, so whatever it is, it's plausible to be used scientifically.

What I read here is that there is an energy able to push whole galaxies apart at an increasing rate. That opens options for a form of anti-gravity. Putting dark energy inside structures might be able to push against material, negating part of all of the gravity.

As an addition, I would use not solid structures but intentionally use hollow lightweight structures to decrease the gravity from the overall structure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With the assumption that dark energy is a scalar field, not the cosmological constant it is a solid principle to put behind an antigravitation device. I will accept this answer if nothing better will come up.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly Wait at least 24 hours before accepting, and with this one maybe a bit more. It's not really answerable, but maybe there's something obscure that fits better.

Comment: Trioxidane, your answer had sparked an idea in my head, it is not science-based though. There is a book called Roadside Picnic by Arkady and Boris Strugatsky, there were items that were called "Black spray", they were believed to be some huge space-time chunks with weird geometry trapped in small volume in our space-time geometry(somewhat of false vacuum but with meta-stable state above ours: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum). This configuration might be used to "store" a lot of dark energy in a small space even if it is cosmological constant, providing the antigravitational effect.

Comment: Even more, if the dark energy is the cosmological constant it may be useful to give the energy to vacuum to move it up to the next meta-stable vacuum state. It will have energy stored in the form of dark energy and provide more antigravitation then usual vacuum. The energy barrier that making this state stable will prevent the usual matter to interact with it in every way except gravitational. It even might be moveable with no effort because this chunk of space's state is determent by its internal energy(volumic and surface) and some kind of volume, and those are not changing if one movеs it.

Answer (score 3):

## Electromagnetism.

To prove your construction as plausible I dont think you need anti gravity. You just need to explain how a structure thousands of kilometres in size doesnt collapse on itself. You need a force to offset the compression force that limits the size of such structure. Rather than anti gravity, I propose good old proven electromagnetism.

I present https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_fountain as an example of such a structure. Thousands of tiny pellets shoot around at high speeds, interacting with electromagnetic coils within the structure in a carefully controlled, monitored, way, applying tension or compression forces through the pellet stream, rather than through the material the structure is made of.

The concrete and metal in such a structure is not structural. The structural members are actually moving pellets. And the limits to how big you can build is how much power you have to power your coil guns at the base.

Using such design you can have a structure made of metal and concrete span thousands of kilometres without stressing the concrete or metal to breaking point.

If the power cuts, the structure can stay standing for a few hours (see wikipedia link), but a permanent blackout will destroy the structure.

Comment: This is a good suggestion to use some external force to compensate the gravity. The problem with the all active means(with non-gravitational nature) for suppressing gravity is that they are not really suppressing it. On a relatively small scale, it will help, but when your construction's mass increases, it starts to have its own gravitational field. If construction grows it makes its gravitation to play the major role and the weight of things will increase. On larger scales, everything on outwards layers of structure will collapse under their own weight because gravity is not shielded

Answer (score 3):

### The best way is to not have to develop new physics, or break existing physics. Use what we know instead.

So perhaps an engineering solution instead: ie. use existing physical principles but just think big or a little out of the box.

For instance:

- **Active Support** - Structures built today are what you would call 'Passive Support'. This is usually simply compression or tension of building elements, however there are limitations to this that limits size. But if you add energy ([Active Structural Support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_structure)) to the system you can create much larger structures, such as [Space Fountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_fountain), [Launch Loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_loop) and other systems that require energy via fluid or cables to counteract their weight. This enables structures that are colossal, with the constant input of energy, and all you need is to find the energy and to dissipate their heat.
- **Centrifugal force** - Why not have the city orbit, much like layers of a dyson swarm around a star, but this time around a planet. Or [similar to an orbital ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_ring). The rings have cables / mass inside that rotate in orbit, supplying the outward force necessary to suspend the city. Again, just a matter of adding energy to counteract friction in this case.
- **Counterweight** - Having large asteroids in Geosynchronous orbit with tensioned cables to 'hang' the city on. This is similar to the [Space Elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) concept, perhaps using carbon nanotubes as a material to enable suspension. There is in fact no limit to the size of your city here.
- **Atmospheric Pressure** - [JP Aerospace experimented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JP_Aerospace) briefly with suspending a 'Dark Sky Station' ie. city in the sky as a stepping off point for high-altitude airships. You can have extraordinarily large helium or hydrogen balloons that suspend the city structures.

These ideas are actually grounded in reality, and when multiplied to the extreme there is no reason why they cannot form large suspended, multilayered kilometre high cities. The engineering challenges need to be overcome, but this is nothing compared to trying to invent new theories of physics that replace proven existing ones.

Comment: You are right except that the existing physics does not explain how the antigravitation will work for it to be consistent. That is also the reason why I asked the question here. Everything that involves mechanical supports is doomed to fail due to weight increase with the increase of mass of the construction. The centrifugal force though might be the key. It is not the antigravitation, but the ring-like structures can be theoretically built with its help, while the spherical can not. Thank you for your suggestions though, they are quite creative

Comment: @FrogOfJuly Thanks FrogOfJuly. It is worth noting every force _is_ an 'antigravity' force if it is simply in the opposite direction of gravity.

Comment: That is true formally, but in practice, mechanical forces are applied to some points of the body, and the gravitational force is applied to each point of the body. The consequence of this is purely technical: one can't attach strings and ropes to every point of the body. It strongly contrasts with centrifugal force, which works the same as gravity in this aspect and is perfectly acceptable as a solution of some configurations of the desired structure

Comment: Atmospheric pressure or in a more general way: Archimedes' principle. Best way to build a 11km high skyscraper on Earth, is by placing the ground floor at challenger deep.

Comment: @qqjkztd, the problem with the weight increase with the mass growth of the structure is unsolvable via the Archimedes' principle

Answer (score 1):

I don't think(but might be wrong) that this is possible with your technology level. So, here's a way to make something that most casual readers won't understand but assume that it works for almost any application you happen to need.

Step 1- your purpose(antigrav something)

Give it a fancy (or not) name that basically sums up the purpose of the machine, and maybe slightly suggests the technology used to make it(graverator, gravity + generator). combining 2 words makes for catchy names.

Step 2- How does it work?(You don't know, but the reader doesn't know either, so they'll take your word for it)

Whenever explaining the way your graverator works, have your scientist man begin rambling off an explanation at least a paragraph long, maybe two and hope the reader skips to the interesting parts later. It's a good idea to include something about atoms, nuclear power, quantum whatnots, or whatever sciency stuff you can find on wikipedia. If your reader does read it and recognizes it as BS, the worst that could happen is they give your story a 0 star review.

Step 3- there has to be hazards(maybe a big red button as well)

whenever making experimental technology, there's always some thing that are unknown. even with old technology, there are things that can go wrong(like when your car breaks down). maybe add a few sentences to said scientist man's explanation about how the graverator might reverse the effects and implode your super-structure.

Not sure this helps, but i think its a pretty good catch-all for technology you need to make up for your story.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that I want to know myself how to explain antigravitation in such a way for it to sound truthful considering known physics

Answer (score 1):

There are a few option´s / ways you can solve this problem.

**Just make some Physics up**

By far the easiest way is to make something up. Often times when writing something like this, you will notice that it just cant work with or known Physics. But as they say, there is always new Physics.
So you could say "We found this new Physics that lets us do X". So for example, in your world the "Gravity Particle" is discovered. it has some weird properties but also some sort of charge. Which can either be +1 or -1. By Inverting the Charge, you effectively make Gravity a Repulsiv force. But this can only happen in a Special field that well Inverts the Charge.

**Dont use Gravity**

If you want to stay in the world of real Physics, there aint a lot you can do. You could however make the structure so larg that Gravity isnt that strong to beginn with. The Structure itself could be supported by active support such as Magnets.

**My suggestion**

Make something up. It is way more believable to say "We found new Physics X" then to have some weird explaination.

Comment: This is a good idea to make up some new physics, but for me, it is important for it to rely on undiscovered parts of modern physics and to do not contradict the discovered ones. For the non-gravitational approach, there is a very big problem with weight increase, which leads to size constraints.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly that's part of the problem, antigravity might contradict good swathes of foundational physics. A possibility is that we find a particle that decays into a more massive particle, leaving behind negative mass particles which should be antigravitational. Negative mass opens a lot of doors for things like closed time-like curves and infinite energy. Things that exhibit antigravity could possibly be used to construct wormholes which can be used to time travel, same set of issues.

Comment: Alternatively, there could be physics outside of those currently known. I think star trek does this with "subspace", getting around the whole FTL time travel thing by having the universe embedded in a higher space where all observers agree on things like time and distance. That would fix the antigravity issue, but it would introduce a lot of new fantasy physics.

Comment: @BMF, some research shows that it is not that bad. There are a lot of tensors there, but the conclusion is that it is possible to avoid vacuum decay you are talking about.https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.3327545?casa_token=c8xShsLHKd0AAAAA:OZII_Vy1yi5lYCQPaxGn9vR0M33J9L93mUc3SKtu9CNpyPEljRy_HjyIdrgcIOhkOV19qhVAVYig

Comment: @FrogOfJuly oh, I'm not talking about vacuum decay. I'm talking about causality violation and FTL/time travel. It's pretty easy to set up a time traveling trajectory when you have FTL, and from there it's pretty easy to set up an infinite energy machine. Physics doesn't like infinities very much

Comment: @BMF, the negative mass is really opening some doors, but it is possible not to introduce it directly as it is done with dark energy. FTL and casualty violation is a long shot in my opinion, but you can describe their connection with antigravitation for me to understand better

Comment: @FrogOfJuly (Sorry, SE mobile doesn't allow me to reply in chat.) It's not negative mass alone that is the door, it's the space-time curvature it creates. The Alcubierre FTL concept requires both positive and negative spatial curvature. Positive can be supplied by familiar gravity, while negative will need to be supplied by an antigravity. Regardless of the mechanism, if you've got an antigravity, you can build an Alc. FTL engine and with it, set up a series of trajectories that take you back in time w.r.t special frames of reference. Applied, this can then lead to infinite free lunches.

Comment: @BMF, I need to do some research about The Alcubierre FTL concept, this thing caught me off guard. I think that it is better to forbid time travel by some means. But thank you for mentioning it

Comment: @FrogOfJuly personally, I wouldn't worry about it. [Causality is overrated anyway](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation).

Answer (score 0):

### Negative Matter

Negative matter is not the same thing as antimatter.  Also, since it is not the same as antimatter, it is not expected to react catastrophically with normal matter; so, no need for fancy containment systems.  Negative matter is a theoretical matter that has a negative mass, and therefore a negative gravity and inertia.  By giving your civilization the ability to create Negative matter, you could fill your megastructure with homogeneously spaced negative matter plates which would create a uniform repulsion force canceling out the harmful effects of gravity and inertia inside your megastructure.

While negative matter has not been proven to exist, it is easy to perform mathematical calculations on meaning that the scientific expectations of what negative matter would do if it were discovered are known and well researched.  Having a predictable nature makes it a preffered subject for sci-fi writing because it means that it has the feel of a hard science while still technically being unproven.

The big hurdle you will have to overcome in your audience is the preconception that negative mass automatically results in perpetual run-away motion because so many people associate negative mass so automatically with Albecurrie Warp Drives, but this is pretty easily addressed.  Albecurrie Warp Drives are like magnets where you create a polar difference between two forces: positive and negative mass; however, a reduced mass megastructure would homogenize positive and negative mass; so, like a normal lump of iron, all of the forces at play would be there, just unobservable from the outside because they would cancel themselves out.

The EM bonds between the regular and negative matter would be stronger than the local effects of gravity; so, as a system, the inertia of the regular matter would be stronger than the negative inneria of the negative matter; so, you'd have a stable system.  Technically it would be impossible to completely homogenizing your mega structure; so, it would still be predisposed to fall ever so slightly in one direction, but this can be solved for by giving your structure a spin.  Since its sum inertia and mass is so small, spinning it would be pretty easy for a system this size.  So, you don't need to worry about the normal ridiculous power requirements of spinning a mega-structure.  By spinning it, it might drift left a little bit as it falls one way, but then when it comes around it would drift back the exact same amount for a sum-stationary effect.

Comment: That is a true but negative matter especially with negative inertia mass will lead to very unpredictable consequences. One of the predictable ones is that it will infinitely accelerate from friction with air, thus making it possible to construct a source of unlimited energy. Negative gravitational mass is less devastating but leads to some paradoxes(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass#Runaway_motion), so introducing negative mass directly is not the best way to make fictional antigravitation to be in peace with modern science.

Comment: Runaway motion is solved under one of bimetric gravity theory but as mentioned here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimetric_gravity#cite_note-NR-5) this theory has some conflicts with existing observation, so is not as favorable as GR theory.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly It is predictable in the sense that we can predict, calculate, and engineer around things like Runaway Motion by following a strict and uniform system, as opposed to a soft-science tech that just does whatever you need it to do because that's what makes the scene work.  See updated answer.

Comment: This is might be a great approach, but I personally prefer soft-science to be a little harder, than it usually expected to be. Thank you for your answer and especially for the metaphor of magnets applied to Albecurrie Warp Drive. It might be helpful to sort time travel out of the picture because for me the time travel is too overpowered tool to use.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly FYI: GR theory does not necessarily allow for time travel even at hyper luminal speeds. In the case of the Albecurrie Drive the negative mass would increase your rate of experienced time while the positive mass would slow it down. The effects would cancel out allowing for an FTL traveler to experience time at a normal speed while riding a steep time space curvature (which is what allows for hyperluminal speed even under the restrictions of General Relativity). So you can allow for negative mass without allowing time travel in a harder science system.

Comment: Nosajimiki, can you provide some links for me to read about the negative mass that does not alow time traveling via The Alcubierre drive concept?

Answer (score 0):

I will accept @Trioxidane's answer as it is one that inspired this one. There were some good suggestions in comments and I think that it is worth merging them (with some additions) to make a separate answer.

### Existing theories:

First of all, there is one source of antigravitation(more accurately is to call it gravitational repulsion though) that is scientifically accepted. It called "Dark energy", but the problem is that nobody knows what is this thing. There are two main theories: [Einstein's_cosmological_constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy#Einstein%27s_cosmological_constant) and [Inflationary dark energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy#Inflationary_dark_energy). Cosmological constant stating that dark energy is bounded to space-time so-called vacuum energy. The second theory states that dark energy is some scalar field.

Secondly, it must be mention that the antimatter is sort of a hack for antigravitation because it is [unlikely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-gravity#Fifth_force) to possess such properties, but it is still possible.

---

#### Update about antimatter:

Actually, there is a [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/94/20001/meta) by M. Villata(2011) with a very convincing way of describing antimatter with gravitational repulsion in a framework of General Relativity. This paper introduces antimatter with gravitational repulsion without assigning negative gravitational mass to it and addresses a topic of spin oddness of graviton. Although it received some [critics](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10509-011-0939-8) with it being [addressed](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10509-011-0940-2) later.

---

### Problems

The scalar field theory is promising in terms of explanation of antigravitation. Because the scalar field may have a mediator particle, the same way as the gravitational field has [graviton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) as such. It is not very easy to come up with a way to realistically capture those as these mediator particles behave almost the same as photons in terms of interactions.

On the other hand, the cosmological constant theory is more favorable from the scientific point of view but less promising for antigravitational effect explanation. If dark energy is bounded to space there is no way to extract it.

### False vacuum

With this in mind let's explore one other concept: [False Vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum). The hypothesis is that there are some other states of vacuum that are meta-stable. Usually, it is used in a set up when our space-time is in the meta-stable state, and collapsing to the true vacuum may have a devastating effect on everything including matter itself. But there is another approach. Let's assume that we are in the true vacuum state, but the false vacuum state is also possible. It will require a very high energy density to reach, for example, such energy density may be unleashed when the back hole evaporates or something similar happens.

[image: False vacuum illustration from wikipedia]

#### Black spray

The idea is that if it is reached - it is metastable and the energy barrier is high enough to provide this stability for the time that is comparable with the universe age.

This state is defined only by the "volume" of space that reached such a state, the energy of this state, and the surface energy. The surface energy minimum is providing us with the spheric form of this volume. From a thermodynamic point of view if partial derivatives of these quantities w.r.t some parameters are zero it means that changing of those parameters is not resulting in force, so one can expect to be able to move this bubble of new space. Its absolute value of mass(gravitational and inertial) will be defined by the energy of the metastable state by Einstein's formula of $E = mc^2$. The energy barrier which provides metastability will prevent interaction of usual matter with the space-time of another nature preventing the need for new physics.

So it will look like the "Black spray" from "Roadside Picnic" by Arkady and Boris Strugatsky. It will be almost indestructible as the energy barrier which provides metastability must be breached for the usual matter to pass-through this type of space. If it breached though, the "Black spray" will release all its energy of the $E = mc^2$ amount.

### Dark energy + False vacuum

The connection between the false vacuum idea and the dark energy is that the energy of metastable space-time is needed to be stored somewhere and with cosmological constant theory in place, it will be stored as vacuum energy thus providing the stronger antigravitational effect than usual space. With the scalar field, it is a little bit trickier because there must be no other fields for the energy to be stored in dark matter's scalar field, but this just requires to be able to provide **really** empty space and I think it is manageable to provide a realistic mechanism to obtain such space.

### Conclusion

The antigravity is provided by the dark energy that is kind of energy of the empty space(vacuum energy). If one will be able to provide a vacuum with so much energy density that part of it will reach the metastable state it will mean that the magnitude of gravitational repulsion will increase as more dark energy will appear. Metastability will provide the spatial locality of "volume" of new space and stability w.r.t external forces.

Answer (score 0):

**Lens.**

[image: convex lens]
http://www.funscience.in/study-zone/Physics/RefractionOfLight/FormationOfDifferentTypesOfImagesByConcaveLens.php

Consider light.  It is kin to gravity in some ways.  It propagates thru space and also thru different media which occupy space.  It is possible to alter the course of light by having it propagate thru a different medium.  It could be a different medium occupying space, like a glass lens.  It could be space which is different because it is bent around a mass - [gravitational lensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens).

Gravity propagates thru space and thru all media that occupy space.  But like light [it is possible to bend gravity waves via gravitational lensing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11809). Different regions of space can have different properties as regards the propagation of gravity and light.

If it were possible to encompass a region of space with different properties once could use that space to alter gravitational effects between objects on different sides.  In the image above a lens spreads out laser light.  Imagine those beams of light are instead the pull of gravity from the flashlight (become a planet) and something on the other side, like a building.  Refracting the pull decreases the pull.

Is it possible there might be a way to alter space such that light and gravity cannot pass through it?  Or are bent in such a way such that their effects do not reach the far side at all?  A prism is a lens that can do that for light.  Could one build a gravitational prism out of bent space?

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but the problem is that gravitons interact only gravitationally and therefore are bend by mass that adds it's own source of gravitons. This issue in the context of light would be similar if the light was only bendable by light. So it is quite hard to imagine the configuration of light sources to make some volume less lightened then without them. Another issue is that it is better to use a semi-constant electromagnetic field as an analogy for the gravitational field rather than light as light is highly alternating filed.

Comment: @FrogOfJuly - thanks for the good comments.  I was thinking different kinds of empty space might be possible because I have read too much about Alcubierre drives.  I did not realize that gravity bends because of the other gravity; I thought it was because the space it travels thru had changed.  Amateur!  Re the constant field I am not sure those can be bent via different media to propagate thru, and I was trying for the lens analogy.